# How to use variables to subset a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

scratching my head on this one.  Suppose I am exploring the cars dataset

```
data(mtcars)
test_dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
```

I can easily subset the table using something like this:

```
new_dt <- test_dt[cyl == '4', c('disp', 'hp', 'gear')]
```

I get 11 rows of data.  Now suppose I want to create a function wherein I pass the name of the column to filter along with the value of the filter so I can create any combination of data I want.  Something like this:

```
foo <- function(colToFilter, filterValue) {
  new_dt <- test_dt[colToFilter == filterValue, c('disp', 'hp', 'gear')]
  return(new_dt)
}
```

and call it like so:

```
new_dt <- foo('cyl', '4')
```

The function does not throw an error but returns 0 rows.  How can I fix my function so I can return 11 rows like before?  TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make your function work, it should be like this:

```
foo <- function(colToFilter, filterValue) {
 #you need get in order to 'get' the column named cyl
 new_dt <- test_dt[get(colToFilter) == filterValue, list(disp, hp, gear)]
 return(new_dt)
}
```

Out:

```
 > foo('cyl', '4')
     disp  hp gear
 1: 108.0  93    4
 2: 146.7  62    4
 3: 140.8  95    4
 4:  78.7  66    4
 5:  75.7  52    4
 6:  71.1  65    4
 7: 120.1  97    3
 8:  79.0  66    4
 9: 120.3  91    5
10:  95.1 113    5
11: 121.0 109    4
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for, although the snippet I posted works quite nicely.  I did it that way because actually I want to pass both the filter info plus the columns so I can slice and dice any way I choose.  Get was the missing link - cheers.

Comment: I was using an older version of `data.table` that didn't allow a data.frame-like subsetting. I downloaded the latest and indeed it works. Thanks :) and I m very happy to help.

Comment: It's sometimes more efficient to use indices, so `DT[val, on=col, j]` or using auto-indexing.

Comment: Another option is `eval(as.name(` i.e. `test_dt[eval(as.name(colToFilter)) == filterValue, list(disp, hp, gear)]`